# Messenger BOT - falback to opertator

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I'm new to Messenger platform and I'm developing a help desk BOT integrated with Facebook Messenger (on a Facebook Page).
I'm wondering on the best practice to fallback/redirect a conversation to a "real agent/operator" (when the BOT is unable to undestand or help the user).
Is it possible to redirect  to another page? alert an operator? ...
I was only considering the various possibilities and best practices .... any advice is welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: The bot is _your_ script, so of course it can "alert an operator" ... all you need to do is _implement_ it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my chatbot, is that when a user wants to talk to a real agent, he presses on a button called "Talk to Support". (I'll not talk about when this button is sent, you can make your own criteria)

Now in my database, there's a column "Chatting with Support", it becomes "true" when the user presses on the "Talk to Support" button, and as long as it's true, the chatbot script will ignore every message from this user.

Now the important part: when the user wants to go back to the chatbot?

I gave my agents a string like "Cancel Chat Session". And whenever a user wants to go back to the chatbot, my agents type "Cancel Chat Session".

What happens is that I subscribed my webhook to messaging_echoes event, which simply sends every message my agents send to any user to my chatbot aswell.

You know the rest, I'll check every request in my chatbot if it's an Echo, the check the text, if it's "Cancel Chat Session", I'll set the column "Chatting with Support" to false for the user, and he's back to the chatbot.

Check Facebook documentation for messaging_echoes events:
[messaging_echoes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-echo)

I hope you could make use of this :)